# How to include the (printed) page number in a table footer

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a document for print (more specifically--converting to PDF with WeasyPrint) that will include a header & footer on every page and I want to include a page number in the footer. I've been able to repeat the header & footer following [this guide](https://medium.com/@Idan_Co/the-ultimate-print-html-template-with-header-footer-568f415f6d2a), but the gist is the whole thing is a `table`--a `thead` and `tfoot` which repeat every page, then the content is in the middle.

To get the page number, I've tried this in the footer:

```css
.page-num:after {
  counter-increment: page;
  content: counter(page)
}
```

```html
<footer>
  ...
  <div class="page-num"><div/>
</footer>
```

But it only shows page 1 for every page:
[image]

So I tried using the `@page` rule:

```css
@page {
  @bottom-right-corner {
    content: counter(page);
  }
}
```

This displays the number and it increments correctly, but it's pushed down below the footer:
[image]

So I need to either:

A) Get the `.page-num` value to increment each page, or

B) Push the `@bottom-right-corner` page number up into the footer (or at least make it look like that)

Is there a way to accomplish this?